# Space complexity of a variant of st-connectivity

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, space-complexity

Consider a variant of STCON, called 2STCON, which is defined like this:

$$2STCON = \{\langle G,u,v \rangle \} \mid \text{$G$ is a graph with } \mathit{two} \text{ paths from $u$ to $v$} \} $$

This means the only difference to the "normal" STCON is that there are two paths instead of just one between $u$ and $v$.

I need to show that 2STCON belongs to NL.

What is the  best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual proof that STCON is in NL works as follows: you guess a path from $u$ to $v$, and verify it step by step.

A very similar proof works for 2STCON: you guess two paths from $u$ to $v$, and verify them step by step. As you verify them, you also verify that they are different: either the length is different, or the $i$-th vertex is different, for some $i$.